# Reading a text file as bytes (byte by byte) using delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I would like to read a UTF-8 text file byte by byte and get the ascii value representation of each byte in the file. Can this be done? If so, what is the best method?

My goal is to then replace 2 byte combinations that i find with one byte  (these are set conditions that I have prepared)

for example, If I find a 197 followed by a 158 (decimal representations), i will replace it with a single byte 17

I don't want to use the standard delphi IO operations

```
AssignFile
ReSet
ReWrite(OutFile);
ReadLn
WriteLn
CloseFile
```

Is there a better method? Can this be done using `TStream` (Reader & Writer)?

Here is an example test I am using. I know there is a character (350) (two bytes) starting in column 84. When viewed in a hex editor, the character consists of 197 + 158 - so i am trying to find the 198 using my delphi code and can't seem to find it

```
FS1:= TFileStream.Create(ParamStr1, fmOpenRead);
try
 FS1.Seek(0, soBeginning);
 FS1.Position:= FS1.Position + 84;
 FS1.Read(B, SizeOf(B));
 if ord(B) = 197 then showMessage('True') else ShowMessage('False');
finally
 FS1.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This makes little sense. How can you replace character 350, aka U+015E, with ASCII 17 which is a control character DC1? Are you really going to hard code the UTF-8 representation of every single Unicode code point? Why would you want to reimplement this? What are you really doing?

Comment: Your seeking is bizarre. Just write `FS1.Position := 84`. Does your hex editor start at column 1 or column 0. If it is column 1, then you need to write `FS1.Position := 83`.

Comment: The other thing you did not say is what type is `B`. Is it a `Byte`? If so you don't need to do `ord()` on it. Which makes me suspect it is in fact `Char`. Which is a two byte UTF-16 char. And that would explain why you don't get `ord(B)=197`.

Comment: I did change the FS1.position to what you recommended. In the past, i did try B as a Char and yes, it is currently a Byte. I changed it back to char and still do not get the 197 in the correct position. I tried going back one and goign forward one as well incase the poistion was off by one

Comment: Why would you try it as char. I told you not to do that. You are hurtling around like a headless chicken trying things at random. If you don't get this 197 that you crave, what do you get? Be methodical. Dump out a few bytes and match it up against your hex editor.

Comment: And my other question. Why convert U+015E to ASCII 17, aka DC1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to convert a text file from UTF-8 to ASCII. That's quite simple:

```
StringList.LoadFromFile(UTF8FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
StringList.SaveToFile(ASCIIFileName, TEncoding.ASCII);
```

The runtime library comes with all sorts of functionality to convert between different text encodings. Surely you don't want to attempt to replicate this functionality yourself?

I trust you realise that this conversion is liable to lose data. Characters with ordinal greater than 127 cannot be represented in ASCII. In fact every code point that requires more than 1 octet in UTF-8 cannot be represented in ASCII.

Comment: This actually got me over to using TStringStream, where I was able to read the entire UTF-8 file, now I need to step through it though, and change some characters, before saving it to another encoded type - thanx

Comment: Well, I'm not convinced this is the answer to your question. I still really cannot fathom out what you are trying to do. For the life of me I can't see where ASCII DC1 appears. Hey ho.

Comment: I also cannot find the reason to replace "Latin Capital Letter S with cedilla" with ASCII #17, but it should be )

Comment: Maybe it's encryption by obfuscation :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use TFileStream to read all data from file to, for isntance, array of bytes, and later check for utf8 sequence. 
Also please note that utf8 sequence can contain more than 2 bytes.

And, in Delphi there is a function Utf8ToUnicode, which will convert utf8 data to usable unicode string.

Comment: Utf8ToUnicode converts UTF-8 to UTF-16, but OP apparently wants UTF-8 to ASCII

Comment: I am currently using TFile Stream, I will edit my code above to reflect a certain test I am doing to look for a 350 (2 bytes) which when viwed in a Hex editor, shows the two bytes as 197 & 158 respectively. So, i am looking for that 350 and wating to replace those two bytes with a single byte (17)

Comment: Can you please describe, why do you need to replace it with 17? We are really wondering about this )

Answer (score 0):

You asked the same question 5 hours later in another topic, the answer od which better addresses your specific question:

[Replacing a unicode character in UTF-8 file using delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868914/)