# Replacing a unicode character in UTF-8 file using delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to replace character (decimal value 197) in a UTF-8 file with character (decimal value 65)

I can load the file and put it in a string (may not need to do that though)

```
SS := TStringStream.Create(ParamStr1, TEncoding.UTF8);
SS.LoadFromFile(ParamStr1);
//S:= SS.DataString;
//ShowMessage(S);
```

However, how do i replace all 197's with a 65, and save it back out as UTF-8?

```
 SS.SaveToFile(ParamStr2);
 SS.Free;
```

-------------- EDIT ----------------

```
reader:= TStreamReader.Create(ParamStr1, TEncoding.UTF8);
 writer:= TStreamWriter.Create(ParamStr2, False, TEncoding.UTF8);

 while not Reader.EndOfStream do
 begin
  S:= reader.ReadLine;
  for I:= 1 to Length(S)  do
  begin
   if Ord(S[I]) = 350 then
   begin
    Delete(S,I,1);
    Insert('A',S,I);
   end;
  end;
  writer.Write(S + #13#10);
 end;

 writer.Free;
 reader.Free;
```

Comment: UTF-8 is one byte length, so no decimal value 300 is possible unless it is a surrogate pair, in which case, it's better to talk about the code points or individual bytes that represent the char. Anyway, what are you trying to accomplish, since it may be related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864643/reading-a-text-file-as-bytes-byte-by-byte-using-delphi-2010)

Comment: None of this makes any sense. This question or your other. You are asking what is known as an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I urge you to tell us the back story. Tell the underlying problem. Let us suggest a solution. The solution you are proposing sounds weak.

Comment: What's wrong with plain old `StringReplace`?

Comment: @Rob That's going to get expensive when we call it for each and every code point >127

Comment: The question at hand says nothing about multiple code points, @David. It asks about replacing just one code point (300).

Comment: I have re-edit the mistake - it is 197 i am trying to replace

Comment: What is so special about 197

Comment: actuall its 197 & 158 back to back which makes up character 350. I am not a unicode expert, so i am only going by what i know. The file is UTF-8. It has turkish characters (only one string of them) in it. One particular character is made up of 197 & 158. I need to remove these and replace it with 65

Comment: Convert it to string, which is UTF16, use StringReplace, and then save it again as UTF8 or ASCII.

Comment: @JakeSnake: byte octet sequence `C5 9E` (dec 197 158) is the UTF-8 encoded `Ş` Unicode character, not the `Å` character.  If you just replace `C5` with `41` (dec 65), but leave `9E` alone, you are converting `Ş` to an invalid UTF-8 sequence. I doubt that is what you really want. If you want to replace `C5 9E` with just `41`, you have to decode the UTF-8 data, then you can use `StringReplace()` to replace `Ş` characters with `A` characters, then encode the result back to UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decimal `197` is hex `C5`, and decimal `65` is hex `41`.

`C5` is not a valid UTF-8 octet by itself, but `41` is.  So I have to assume you are actually referring to Unicode codepoints `U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE` and `U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A` instead.

`U+00C5` is encoded in UTF-8 as `C3 85`, and `U+0041` is encoded as `41`.  To do what you are asking, you have to decode the UTF-8, replace the codepoints, then re-encode back to UTF-8.  `StringReplace()` will work just fine for that, eg:

```
SS := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
SS.LoadFromFile(ParamStr1);

S := StringReplace(SS.DataString, 'Å', 'A', [rfReplaceAll]);

SS2 := TStringStream.Create(S, TEncoding.UTF8);
SS2.SaveToFile(ParamStr2);

SS2.Free;
SS.Free;
```

Or:

```
reader := TStreamReader.Create(ParamStr1, TEncoding.UTF8);
writer := TStreamWriter.Create(ParamStr2, False, TEncoding.UTF8);

while not Reader.EndOfStream do
begin
  S := reader.ReadLine;
  S := StringReplace(S, 'Å', 'A', [rfReplaceAll]);
  writer.WriteLine(S);
end;

writer.Free;
reader.Free;
```

**Update:** based on other comments, it looks like you are not actually interested in Unicode codepoint `U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE`, but rather in `U+015E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA` instead, which is encoded in UTF-8 as `C5 9E`.  If that is true, then simply replace `Å` with `Ş` when calling `StringReplace()` after the UTF-8 data has been decoded:

```
S := StringReplace(S, 'Ş', 'A', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Jake is referring to U+015E